# Validator works as attribute on input but not on form control

Tags: regex, angular

I am trying validation via form-control but when I use the regex via form control, it doesn't seem to validate correctly. When I add the pattern to the input field in the HTML, it works perfectly fine. I am trying to validate a domain name.

```
let regexPattern = "^(?!.* .*)(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$";
this.domainName.setValidators(regexPattern)
```

this method does not work, I can enter words like ".com" and the status is valid where as when I place the same regex on an input, it works

```
<input matInput formControlName="domainName" pattern="^(?!.* .*)(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$" placeholder="Domain Name">
```

Thanks

Comment: Your regex does not match spaces, `(?!.* .*)` is redundant.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.setValidators([Validators.pattern(/^(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$/)])`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if i add that pattern to a variable and then add it, it doesn't validate correctly.

Comment: And how do you do that? `let regexPattern = /^(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$/; this.domainName.setValidators([Validators.pattern(regexPattern)])` must work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly like that

Comment: Can you please post a plunkr showcasing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing validation using setValidators then you have to return your custom validation value of boolean type. 
Here you do not return any data. Code should be like

```
 this.formGroup.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.required, this.checkDomain]);

  checkDomain(control) {
  console.log("string == ");
  console.log(control.value);
  let test = control.value;
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?!.* .*)(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$/)
  if(test.match(pattern)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

and Your pattern attribute in html it wokrs.You can explore from below link.

[Validation examples](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example)

My English not as good.  So avoid if any misunderstanding.